# R: Variable that matches two dataframes by row and column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matching

**SOLVED**

Suppose we have the given:

```
#Defining sample variables    

    set.seed(1) ##Note I didn't set seed for the values below so your numbers will be different

    date <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1', '2015-1-1', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-5', '2015-1-5'))
    variable1 <- runif(6, max=1, min=0)
    date2 <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-5'))
    variable2 <- runif(3, max=2, min=1)
    variable3 <- runif(3, max=5, min=4)
    df1 <- data.frame(date, variable1)
    df2 <- data.frame(date2, variable2, variable3)

#Sample dataframes

    #df1
       Date variable1
1 2015-01-01 0.2655087
2 2015-01-01 0.3721239
3 2015-01-03 0.5728534
4 2015-01-03 0.9082078
5 2015-01-05 0.2016819
6 2015-01-05 0.8983897

   #df2
        Date variable2 variable3
1 2015-01-01  1.646115  4.706171
2 2015-01-03  1.457847  4.549162
3 2015-01-05  1.015068  4.735463
```

I'd like to define some function that spits out a value based on variable2 OR variable3, depending on the value of variable1.

What I have so far:

```
    SomeVariable <- function(x){
            if (x < 0.5) 
                    df2$variable2
            else
                    df2$variable3
    }

    SomeVariable(df1$variable1[1])
[1] 1.646115 1.457847 1.015068
```

But somehow I need to make it so that the function also matches the values of variable1, variable2, and variable3 **by date**.

For example, SomeVariable on the first entry should return only 1.646, and SomeVariable on the last should only return 4.735.

```
    #Final output should be:
         Date  SomeVariable 
    1 2015-01-01 1.646115
    2 2015-01-01 1.646115
    3 2015-01-03 4.549162
    4 2015-01-03 4.549162
    5 2015-01-05 1.015068
    6 2015-01-05 4.735463
```

Comment: Made some edits to OP.

Comment: Edited numbers with set.seed(1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I totally misunderstand what you want, but I don't think you need a complicated function.

Use set seed to get reproducible data

```
set.seed(123)
date <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1', '2015-1-1', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-5', '2015-1-5'))
variable1 <- runif(6, max=1, min=0)
date2 <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1', '2015-1-3', '2015-1-5'))
variable2 <- runif(3, max=2, min=1)
variable3 <- runif(3, max=5, min=4)
df1 <- data.frame(date, variable1)
df2 <- data.frame(date, variable2, variable3)
```

Add column variable1 to df2 by date using the match() function

```
Indices<-match(df2$date, df1$date)
df2$variable1 <- df1$variable1[Indices]
```

Add column SomeVar depending on value of variable1

```
df2$SomeVar[df2$variable1<0.5] <- df2$variable2[df2$variable1<0.5] 
df2$SomeVar[df2$variable1>0.5] <- df2$variable3[df2$variable1>0.5]
```

Comment: The output is very close to what I'm looking for, but I'd like to put it as a column in df1 instead (as there are multiple values of SomeVar for each date).

Also this was a simplified example, the real one I'm trying to do has about 8 variables in df2 so the SomeVariable will be partitioned like (x < 0.1 = var2, x < 0.2 = var3, ...)

Comment: Hold on, reversed your code and used a merge() function to take care of the multiple entry issue and I think it may work..